# VS Code show error using get in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get an array from my API, but when write the `GET` method this show me the next error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

#### Code

```
grupos.$inject = ['$http'];

function grupos($http){

    function obtenerGrupos(){

        var url;

        url = 'http://localhost:1890/Grupos1';

        return {
            $http.get(url);
        };

    };

    return {
        obtenerGrupos: obtenerGrupos
    };

}
```

I use VS Code, and, if i change the **.** for **:**, show me that

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

[image: image error http.get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to brush up on your basic JS syntax.

You don't need the curly brackets around the call to `$http.get()`. Remove those, and everything will be fine.